# AuditorAware not providing latest value to Spring Batch threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch application where we use SimpleJobLauncher. In that, we have Rest request to trigger batch job on excel which while saving the entity in writer stage, does not pick AuditorAware latest set through HTTP thread received.

I have tried setting the username in JobParameter and then fetching same in writer to set the username thread local variable but that is also not getting picked.

I am using Threadlocal to store the user once we receive a request which provides the user information to auditoraware.

```
public static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> USERNAME = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        if (USERNAME.get() != null) {
            return () -> Optional.of(USERNAME.get());
        }
        return () -> Optional.of(WebConstant.DEFAULT_USER);
    }

public class HeaderInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {

    /**
     * This implementation always returns {@code true}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        String username = request.getHeader("username");
        if(null == username) {
            throw new UserNotProvidedException("USER_NOT_PROVIDED");
        }
        USERNAME.set(username);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AuditorAware is called by a spring application event, if you specified task executor for event multicaster, my way to solve this issue is to create a customized AuditingEventListener, invoke AuditingEventListener within the same thread

```java
    @Bean(name = "applicationEventMulticaster")
    public ApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {
        SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster = new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {

            private ResolvableType resolveDefaultEventType(ApplicationEvent event) {
                return ResolvableType.forInstance(event);
            }

            @Override
            public void multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent event, ResolvableType eventType) {
                ResolvableType type = (eventType != null ? eventType : resolveDefaultEventType(event));
                Executor executor = getTaskExecutor();

                for (ApplicationListener<?> listener : getApplicationListeners(event, type)) {
                    if (listener instanceof AuditingEventListener) {
                        invokeListener(listener, event);
                        return;
                    }

                    executor.execute(() -> invokeListener(listener, event));
                }
            }
        };

        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("s-event-");
        multicaster.setTaskExecutor(executor);
        return multicaster;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you put the username in a `ThreadLocal` in one thread and then try to access it from another thread.

It should be obvious from the documentation of [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) that this won't work.

> each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable.

You need to pass the user name to the batch job by some other means.
I never used Spring Boot, but [this article](https://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/07/passing-values-between-spring-batch.html) describe the `JobContext` and how to use it.

I'm not sure if you can inject any of those into your `AuditorAware`.
Alternatively you can put the value in the `ThreadLocal` at the beginning of whatever runs in a single `Thread` in your setup.

Comment: @Jean Schauder, Even I had the same understanding that why I was tried setting the username in writer thread of Spring batch but things for more weird when I used below change on our entities. ***`@PrePersist
  public void prePersist() {
      String createdByUser = WebConstant.USERNAME.get();
      this.createdBy = createdByUser;
      this.updatedBy = createdByUser;
  }
    
  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
      String updatedBy = WebConstant.USERNAME.get();
      this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
  }`***

Comment: With above-mentioned code, it started working contrary to my understanding which is InheritableThreadLocal can fetch values from parent thread but here writer thread in Spring batch is able to fetch the values.